If a person does not have green cone cells, then will he see the colour purple as purple?
If a person does not have green cone cells, then will he see the colour purple as purple? Since by default he should see green.
I am asking this because our brain interprets light that has red component and blue component as purple but it ideally should interpret it as green. Since we already have cones to detect green light our brain interprets this light as purple.
